# SDL_Delay() while getting events (kinda nooby)

Tags: c++, sdl

*C++, SDL 2*

Im making a disco simulator thats just loops through pictures and plays music.

(Epilepsy warning) https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOBQe.jpg

Basically I want to run this code

```
while (isPartying){
        currentImage = image1;
        SDL_BlitSurface(currentImage, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
        SDL_Delay(25);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

        currentImage = image2;
        SDL_BlitSurface(currentImage, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Delay(25);

        currentImage = image3;
        SDL_BlitSurface(currentImage, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Delay(25);

        //image 3, 4, 5 and so on

}
```

while getting events all the time.

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0){
        if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT){
            isPartying = false;
        }
    }
```

I want it to get events while Im in the middle of the isPartying loop. Now it only checks for events at the beginning (or the end, depends on where I put the event loop of course). Anyone know a better way to wait for the next picture then SDL_Delay()? Or maybe even have another solution

Ano

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want to do is to achieve *two things at a time*.
You have two options:

- Using `SDL_Thread`, but I prefere to not use threads when another solution is possible (because you may have to deal with semaphores or mutexes)
- Using `SDL_TimerCallback` (some would say that too much timers kill the flow of the code, but it's what we gonna use)

Here is a code sample (NB: you must pass `SDL_INIT_TIMER` to `SDL_Init()`).

```
void IsPartying()    {
    SDL_Event ev;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev)){
        if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
}

uint32_t ChangeImage(uint32_t interval, void* param)    {
    int *imageNb = param;
    (*imageNb)++
    return interval
}

void Processing() {
    // Store your images in SDL_Surface **imageArray
    int imageNb = 0;
    SDL_TimerID t = SDL_AddTimer(25, ChangeImage, &imageNb);

    while (IsPartying())    {
        SDL_BlitSurface(imageArray[imageNb], NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_Delay(1); // Release proc charge
    }
    SDL_RemoveTimer(SDL_TimerID);
}
```

Of course you still need to check if you iterated over all the images, else you'll got a nice `segfault` while trying to access an unallocated cell of the array.